# How to check List<Guid> contains a Guid C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
public class Skip : BaseModel
{
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> SkippedIDs { get; set; }
}
```

I have an object with `List<Guid>`

```
var skippedMe = await SkipCollection.Aggregate().Match(s => s.UserID == profile.Id).FirstAsync();
```

I am trying to avoid skipped profiles that should not load in the list

```
var Result1 = await ProfileCollection.Aggregate()
                    .Match(p => (skippedMe.SkippedIDs.Any() ? !skippedMe.SkippedIDs.Contains(p.Id) : true))
                    .ToListAsync();
```

*I have `List<Profile>`, I need to avoid loading the skipped Profiles in the `List<Profile>`, using aggregate and match with the help of MongoDB driver*

Comment: Please [edit] this question and clarify what exactly you want. The 3 `bResult` check for very different stuff and it's impossible to guess what result should `bResult` contain. Also, `bResult` is a terrible name, please name it meaningfully.

Comment: Your edit didn't make things any clearer. Are you trying to exclude `Skip` instances that have an entry in `SkippedIDs` with the value of `UserID`?

Comment: SkippedIDs contains a list of skipped Profile Id's. UserID is also a profile Id, which who logged in to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution: If there are no items `FirstOrDefaultAsync` returns null, so we can instantiate the object without getting an exception.

```
var skippedMe = await SkipCollection.Aggregate()
                .Match(s => s.UserID == profile.Id)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync() ??
                new Skip() 
                { 
                    SkippedIDs = new List<Guid>() { Guid.Empty } 
                };
```

> If there have any other solutions or shorthand, plz let me know

```
var Result1 = await ProfileCollection.Aggregate()
                    .Match(p => !skippedMe.SkippedIDs.Contains(p.Id))
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
var Result1 = await ProfileCollection.Aggregate()
                .Match(p => (skippedMe.SkippedIDs.Any() ? !skippedMe.SkippedIDs.Contains(p.Id) : true))
                .ToListAsync();
```

with

```
var Result1 = await ProfileCollection.Aggregate()
                .Match(p => (skippedMe.SkippedIDs.Count() > 0 && !skippedMe.SkippedIDs.Contains(p.Id))
                .ToListAsync();
```

Are your sure your objects/ values can't be null?

```
var skippedMe = await SkipCollection.Aggregate().Match(s => s.UserID == profile.Id).FirstAsync();
```

Code like this can easily produce null pointer exceptions. If there is always a match, this is perfectly fine, if not try it with FirstOrDefaultAsync and handle null values appropriately.

Comment: In case the user doesn't skip any profile means we will get a null value.